# SOLR Response size limitation

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4

When i query SOLR with "*" I want to know what is the maximum items i can receive from the solr.

I am sending 2 queries, in one I ask 124K rows and in one 125K, the 125K fails, I would like to understand why. I could not find anything in the SOLR logs

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?%22start=0&rows=125000&q=*&fl=UniqueId,%20entity_id,%20data_unit_id,%20score&wt=tcp&host=10.175.2.127&port=8985&queryId=4&qt=standard&debugQuery=false%22
```

I Receive the following error:

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /solr/select. Reason:

{trace=java.lang.NullPointerException
,code=500}
```

When i am running the query:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?%22start=0&rows=124000&q=*&fl=UniqueId,%20entity_id,%20data_unit_id,%20score&wt=tcp&host=10.175.2.127&port=8985&queryId=4&qt=standard&debugQuery=false%22
```

I get good response:

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">6383</int>
<lst name="params">
<str name="port">8985</str>
<str name="debugQuery">false"</str>
<str name="host">10.175.2.127</str>
<str name="fl">UniqueId, entity_id, data_unit_id, score</str>
<str name="q">*</str>
<str name="queryId">4</str>
<str name="qt">standard</str>
<str name="wt">tcp</str>
<str name=""start">0</str>
<str name="rows">124000</str>
</lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="0" start="0" maxScore="0.0"/>
</response>
```

SOLR Logs of error when sending 125K rows query:

```
INFO  - 2015-02-10 10:26:40.122; org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore; [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/select params={port=8985&debugQuery=false"&host=10.175.2.127&fl=UniqueId,+entity_id,+data_unit_id,+score&q=*&queryId=4&qt=standard&wt=tcp&"start=0&rows=125000} hits=1320877 status=500 QTime=1420 
ERROR - 2015-02-10 10:26:40.123; org.apache.solr.common.SolrException; null:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid version (expected 2, but 60) or the data in not in 'javabin' format
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:302)
```

Design is to send Http request, and the response is read with TCPClient, StreamReader and NetworkSteam (C#), I dont get to reading response since exception is thrown when sending the HttpWebRequest.

Comment: Could you provide logs about NPE?

Comment: Within the response you get a value called `numFound`. This contains the total number of documents that were matched by the search performed. Is this what you need?

Comment: @cheffe I dont get response when i query 125k rows.

Comment: I understand this, you cannot get responses that large. You will need a different approach then. But you write: I want to know what is the maximum items i can receive from the solr. This would be answerable with the numfound value.

Comment: Thanks all, what i want to know, and i assume could be acheived only with debugging the java code of solr, this exception is not acceptable by me, i would like to get a correct error.

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's a very bad practice to set **rows** to that big number. For most of the applications - it should be done in a batch, like have **rows = 50** and change **start**, when you iterate over results.

It's a very bad practice, because complexity for getting top **K** docs of **N** documents require **O(K * log(N))** and in your case **N** = number of all docs, **K** - is a **rows** param.